# High sum implies high individual value

Tags: probability

Let $a_1,\dots,a_n,b_1,\dots,b_n,c_1,\dots,c_n$ be independent uniform values from $(0,1)$. Let $S$ be the set of all indices $i$ such that $a_i+b_i+c_i>2$. Is it true that $$\frac{\sum_{i\in S}{a_i}}{|S|}>\frac{2}{3}$$ with high probability when $n$ is large?

This seems like an application of Chernoff bound, but I'm not sure how to set up the variables.

Comment: I would think this probability would be bounded away from both zero and one, because to have $a_i+b_i+c_i>2$, one of the three must be larger than 2/3 but it could be just one, for example you could have $a_i=0.9,b_i=0.6,c_i=0.6$.

Comment: I'm not sure about the formality, but $P(\sum a_i + b_i + c_i > 2) = 1$.

Comment: @Ian I see the intuition you provide, but the conclusion is not clear to me.

Comment: @OFRBG The sum over $a_i+b_i+c_i$ for all $i$ is going to be almost certainly larger than $2$, that is true, but it doesn't help with the question.